# Executing Fortran file with Lapack Subroutine(program exited with code: 127)

Tags: lapack, geany, lapacke

After installing Lapack libraries in CAE Linus 2013, I tried to run a fortran file calling Lapack subroutine with the help of '.sh' file in 'Geany'. My program exited with code 127. Please help!

Terminal Photo:
[image: Photo of a terminal window 1]
[Terminal photos][3]

Error Photo [image: Photo fo the error]

Comment: The first error is probably because of "...' (rather than "..." or '...'), and the second one may be il (eye-el) rather than i1 (eye-one)? (Also, probably -llibblas => -lblas and -lliblapack => -llapack)

Comment: serously now? a photo of the physical screen? including the glare and all.